# PHP - Include or Header

Tags: php

I need some advice on the best way to set up a process that I am running which runs a series of scripts that run one after the other and will potentially be a cron job.
Each one can be run on its own but depends on the previous job having run successfully for it to work.
My sequence is as follows:

1. Set variables for the jobs.
2. Extract a csv file from an email when it arrives.
3. Parse that csv file into the database
4. Generate a series of PDF files based on the database with the new data and 1 above.
5. Email those PDFs to the required recipients.

Given the above I cannot do any step until the previous one is complete.

Each step is its own php script.

What I’d like advice on is what the best method to set this up is.

At the moment I have a single page with all the above as include statements in one page.

Each one runs and then the next runs etc.

I’m not sure if this fairly long script is the best way or whether I should actually use a Header statement to make each one run and then return to my main action page with some variables confirming the previous script has run.

Does it make any difference?

Comment: Better if you use require

Answer (score 1):

Better if you use require because require throws error if it doesn't get the file but include doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Create a checkpoint in the db, when one job is complete set it to "0"

Comment: nice idea - will work with this - in fact will expand this to including dates that have run as well to prevent rerunning. thanks